# Double entries in Kibana/elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am using `logstash 1.4.1` and `elasticsearch 1.1.1`. My setup is showing an issue:

For every new line (log) added to the log file I am getting two entries in Kibana i.e every log entry is showing twice in Kibana. However when I check my logstash console, the log line is showing only once.

My elasticserach console:

```
[2014-11-20 14:14:42,229][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Brothers Grimm] [logstash-2014.11.20] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], shards [5]/[1], mappings [_default_]
[2014-11-20 14:14:42,672][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Brothers Grimm] [logstash-2014.11.20] update_mapping [logs] (dynamic)
```

Any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that two logstash instances were running. One was in the background which I was not aware of. So I killed one and it's working now.